# Detecting as the last child of the parent under class="cond"

Tags: javascript

**contenteditable div**

```
((grade >= passingMark) && (grade<101))
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="cond frag">(<span class="cond frag">(grade >= passingMark)</span> && <span class="cond frag">(grade<101)</span>)</span>
```

How would i know if i am the last child of cond  or there is no next sibling following me `(grade<101)`

Something like (in a loop):

```
$elem = $('.frag').eq(fragNum);

if ($elem.nextAll('.cond').length === 0 ) {
    alert('last child detected');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "How would i know ..." you mean "In JavaScript, how would I get..."

MooTools makes it easy:

```
var last = document.getElement('.cond').getLast('span');
```

In this case, document.getElement will get the first element that matches .cond in document.

There will be a simple jQuery equivalent too.

If you are using native JS, you run into problems as there is no native support for "getElemntByClassName" in IE<9. There are a bunch of frameworks and tools to bridge these browser gaps like MooTools, JQuery, Prototype, etc, but if you  need native and know the index position of the span with class .cond within a specific container, you could try:

```
var conds = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].getElementsByTagName("span");
var last = conds[conds.length-1];
```

Where document is your specific container and 0 is the position (first in container).

If this is the only problem you would like to solve, there is this 2008 "getElementsByClassName" solution that still works nicely is IE<9 by Robert Nyman - http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/nujr7/1/

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cond');
var totalElements = elements.length;
var lastElement = elements[totalElements -1];
```

Added console.logs to illustrate this clearer in the fiddle.

Hope this helps.